# SwipeRefreshLayout обновление снизу

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

Добрый день. Я использую `SwipeRefreshLayout` в моём `RecyclerView`. Но я нигде на нашел, как сделать обновление при свайпе внизу списка, а не вверху. Подскажите, как это реализовать и можно ли вообще так сделать используя стандарный `SwipeRefreshLayout`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SwipeRefreshLayout` не поддерживает pull-to-refresh снизу, но на `github`-e есть решение, которое Вам подойдет. [Ссылка](https://github.com/JohannBlake/SwipeRefreshLayoutBottom)

Comment: Очень странно, что гугл не добавил поддержку снизу. Спасибо за ссылку. Скажите пожалуйста, встроенные библиотеки с `github` -а можно использовать в платных приложениях на google play?

Comment: Да, думаю проблем не должно быть

Comment: Да  там MIT лицензия, полная свобода использования. 
Насчет то что не добавили, где-то есть видео по им словам, это нарушает концепцию, также как и overscroll refresh, не знаю исправили сейчас или ещё нет.

Answer (score 2):

Лично я юзаю вот [эту](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout) либу, там есть возможность обновиться и сверху и снизу

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, здесь и правда можно сразу и сверху, и снизу обновлять. Пригодится в дальнейшем.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как её добавить и использовать в своём проекте? на `github`-е не туториала..

Comment: @Denis422 "на github-е не туториала.." Значит вы плохо смотрели, там **ЕСТЬ** туториал, а именно читаете **Usage**, там всё и написано, как в XML добавить и как заюзать в коде. В **Customezation** написано, что если вы хотите, чтобы обновлялось и сверху-вниз и снизу-вверх, то нужно дабавить **app:direction="both"** в XML

Comment: Это я видел, так и сделал. Но вылетает с ошибкой nullPoiuntException, хотя стандартная гугловская, поставленная точно также - нет.

Comment: @Denis422 Если у вас Exception вылетел, то неплохо было бы логи посмотреть, на что именно ругается. У меня эта либа работает абсолютно нормально, скорее всего вы что-то не так сделали